# Com exception in sharepoint when trying to add list item with image

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I cannot add news to pages list on my sharepoint site. 
Exception:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.
 Please try again.

 <nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

Problem can be reprodused only when image field in news is set!

What can be wrong with my news here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know exactly what was the source of problem but when definition and content type was removed from site and added again exception dissapead.